# Xcode scrollview not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, interface-builder, scrollview

I'm making a game and need users to sign an End User License Agreement (EULA). The EULA is long and requires a scroll view. I want the screen itself to stay still, so the buttons and header are always present:

Here is a screenshot of my viewController storyboard:

[image]

here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet var eulaView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let width = eulaView.frame.width
    let height = eulaView.frame.height

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    self.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width , height: 2000)
    self.label.text = "Lots of stuff"

}
```

Strangely, if I set self.label.frame's width to 100, it shows up. If I have it at 300, or "width", the label disappears.

No matter what, the scroll view doesn't scroll.

PS: I had it working earlier, but then I tried it on an iPhone X simulator and it was blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set  `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width,height: 2000)`

Sometimes When you change device in storyboard at that time screen was blank may be its bug of xcode.

To find the Dynamic Height Of label Depends on String Of label.

```
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.height
}
```

Comment: any thoughts on how to dynamically edit the contentSize height?

Comment: If you want dynamically edit contentSize you should use constraint, not just add subview

Comment: what about modify the font to fit the size of the entire thing?

Comment: Hi@MasonBallowe, you can set the constraint to increasing Content-Based component and it will increase according to content.